# Form Submit with Ajax into Node Backend

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, forms

I'm new to node and I am trying to do a form submit and pass the data through Ajax and process the data on Node backend. After processing the data, the data should be sent back and displayed on index.html. But before sending back any data, i am already having issues sending the data to node backend.

There are restrictions for this task. I was informed to achieve the above without using any external libraries like express, request etc.

I believe the server.js, index.js, router.js has no problems. But i displayed it below for clarity.
The problem might be in the ajax code and function convert{}. For now, i am just console.logging data at each point to make sure the data passes to node.

Here's my code below, strangely i cannot figure out why it is not working properly, i have spent many hours on this.

i received in the command line the message "Hello World" from function convert{} in the request handler file. So it seems that Ajax is working okay at least on the xhr.open. But the code below the console.log("Hello World"); is not executing(request.addListener). Then it opens my index.html file again, because my command line shows that "/" handler is executed.

Appreciate greatly any advise on fixing this. Thank you!

index.html:

```
        <form method="post" id = "fform">
        <input type="checkbox" id="text1" name="number1" >
        <label for="text1"> Number 1</label><br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="text2" name="number2" >
        <label for="text2"> Number 2</label><br />
        <h4>Select a date</h4>
        <select id="text3" name="month">
            <option value="01">Jan</option>
            <option value="02">Feb</option>
            <option value="03">Mar</option>
            <option value="04">Apr</option>
            <option value="05">May</option>
            <option value="06">Jun</option>
            <option value="07">Jul</option>
            <option value="08">Aug</option>
            <option value="09">Sep</option>
            <option value="10">Oct</option>
            <option value="11">Nov</option>
            <option value="12">Dec</option>
        </select>
        <select id="text4" name="year">
            <option value="2009">2007</option>
            <option value="2009">2008</option>
            <option value="2009">2009</option>
            <option value="2009">2010</option>
            <option value="2009">2011</option>
            <option value="2009">2012</option>
            <option value="2009">2013</option>
            <option value="2009">2014</option>
            <option value="2009">2015</option>
            <option value="2009">2016</option>
        </select>
        <h4>Output Type</h4>
        <input type="checkbox" id="text5" name="table" >
            <label for="text5"> As a Table</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="text6" name="graph" >
            <label for="text6">As a Graph</label><br /><br />
        <<button type="submit" onclick="return showData()" >Submit</button>
```

Index.html script. xhr.send is a string for now for testing purposes.

```
<script>
    function showData() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST","./convert",true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send("foo=bar&lorem=ipsum");
    }
</script>
```

Index.js

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");
var requestHandlers = require("./requestHandlers");

var handle = {};
handle["/"] = requestHandlers.reqStart;
handle["/convert"] = requestHandlers.convert;

server.startServer(router.route, handle);
```

Router.js

```
var url = require("url");

function route(pathname, handle, response, request) {
    console.log("Routing a request for: "+ pathname);

    if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function') {
        handle[pathname](response, request);
    } else {
        console.log("Nothing found for: " + pathname);
        response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("Resource cannot be found!");
        response.end();
    }
}
exports.route = route;
```

Server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function startServer(route, handle) {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        console.log("Requesting for " + pathname + " received.");   
        route(pathname, handle, response, request);
    }
    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(41075);
    console.log("Server is now started.");
}

exports.startServer = startServer;
```

requestHandler.js

```
var qs = require("querystring");
var fs = require("fs");
var url = require("url");

function reqStart(response, request) {
 //processing goes here to open index.html, code hidden, no problem here
}

function convert(request, response) {

    console.log("Hello World");

    request.addListener('data', function(dataChunk) {
        console.log("Received POST chunk'"+dataChunk+"'.");
        request.addListener('end', function() {
            console.log("You've sent: " + dataChunk);
            response.end();
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> onclick="return showData()"
> ```

When you use this 1990s approach to adding event listeners, returning `false` from the function will prevent the default behaviour (i.e. the regular submission of the form) to the URL specified in the `action` attribute (or the current URL if there is no `action` attribute).

You are returning the return value of `showData`. This function has **no `return` statement** so it returns `undefined`.

This does not prevent the regular form submission, so after initiating the Ajax request, the form submits and loads a new page (killing the page running the JavaScript program waiting for the response to the Ajax request).

You need to `return false`.

---

A modern approach would be to bind your event listener with JavaScript, and use the [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method to stop the form submission:

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", showData);

function showData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "./convert");
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("foo", "bar");
    params.append("lorem", "ipsum");
    xhr.send(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use inline event handlers and certainly not on a submit button

Since you are not cancelling the click event (by returning false in the function) you will try to ajax AND submit at the same time

Here is a better way

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("fform").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST","./convert",true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send("foo=bar&lorem=ipsum");
  }) 
})
```

Comment: Thank you! this helps to stop the index.html from reloading. However, the data doesn't seem to pass through, as the console.log("Hello World"); gets printed and then it stops there. the request.addListener('data', etc...){} doesn't run, because the console.log lines within is not executed. Do you know what might have caused this?